# get list of named loglevels

Tags: python, logging

In my application, I'm using `python.logging` for logging.

Now I want to control the loglevel interactively, so i created a combobox hat lets the user select "*ERROR*", "*WARN*", "*INFO*",...

What I don't really like is that currently the values in the combobox are hardcoded.
Instead, I would like to have a list of all "named" loglevels (e.g. both the system defaults, but also those added via `logging.addLevelName`; but not the fake generated loglevels like "*Level 42*")

The best I have come up with so far is to use the `logging._levelNames` dictionary.

But then this seems to be a private member, and I somehow have a bad feeling accessing it directly.

So my question is: what's the proper way to list all currently defined "named" loglevels in Python.

Comment: in python 3.4 the member was renamed to `_levelToName` so you were right with the bad feeling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are only reading values, `logging._levelNames` looks an appropriate solution to me. Keep going with `logging.addLevelName` for setting new values though.

Comment: how to solve compatibility issue of this stuff between Python 2 and Python 3 using six (or other clean way)?

Comment: _levelToName is not accessible, use logging.getLevelName()

Comment: you can also use _nameToLevel for reverse usage in python 3

Comment: `_levelNames` is not available in Python 3. However, a quick look into the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/logging/__init__.py) shows that there are two dicts `_nameToLevel` and `_levelToName` which can be used to get a list of the available log levels. E.g. one can do: `list(logging._nameToLevel.keys())`

Answer (score 6):

You should have a bad feeling about using internal variables, because they can and will change. Case in point, you can no longer access `logging._levelNames` in python 3.

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) the levels are more or less stated as constants, so you can just assume those ones are always available, and then any you add yourself are under your control anyway.

That said, it's a bit silly they don't have a simple method like `logging.listLevels()` to list out all the named levels currently loaded. You should write them a strongly worded letter. Or feature request depending on how much you really care :)

And it should be strongly worded, because the changes is absurdly simple:

file: `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py`

```
def listLevelNames():
    return sorted(_nameToLevel.keys())
```

If you wanted to get really fancy, you could even sort the names by level number.

edit: I made a topic in [comp.lang.python](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.python/c/CsSpMOUMNj4/m/wxTNXVJ_BgAJ). Don't worry, I was very polite.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem while writing the help string of a program that accepts the name of the log level on the command line. As `_levelNames` is a private member that was renamed to `_levelToName` in Python 3.4 and thus cannot/should not get used, I came up with this solution (simplified for SO):

```
print "Levelnames: {}".format(", ".join(
    logging.getLevelName(x)
    for x in xrange(1, 101)
    if not logging.getLevelName(x).startswith('Level')))
```

or, for Python 3.x:

```
print("Levelnames: {}".format(", ".join(
    logging.getLevelName(x)
    for x in range(1, 101)
    if not logging.getLevelName(x).startswith('Level'))))
```

It's not entirely pretty, but it seems portable across all Python versions, and it prints out the level names in ascending order:

```
Levelnames: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL
```

Answer (score 4):

With Python 3.11, [`logging.getLevelNamesMapping()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLevelNamesMapping) was added, which allows to easily inquire the list of log level names:

```py
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLevelNamesMapping()
{'CRITICAL': 50, 'FATAL': 50, 'ERROR': 40, 'WARN': 30, 'WARNING': 30, 'INFO': 20, 'DEBUG': 10, 'NOTSET': 0}
>>> list(logging.getLevelNamesMapping())
['CRITICAL', 'FATAL', 'ERROR', 'WARN', 'WARNING', 'INFO', 'DEBUG', 'NOTSET']
```

Custom levels are also included in the mapping:

```
>>> logging.addLevelName(5, "TRACE")
>>> logging.getLevelNamesMapping()["TRACE"]
5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific function to do what you want, but you have everything you need with `logging._levelNames`.

Take a look at the `addLevelName` definition for example:

```
def addLevelName(level, levelName):
    """
    Associate 'levelName' with 'level'.

    This is used when converting levels to text during message formatting.
    """
    _acquireLock()
    try:    #unlikely to cause an exception, but you never know...
        _levelNames[level] = levelName
        _levelNames[levelName] = level
    finally:
        _releaseLock()
```

So a `getLevelNames()` could be implemented like this:

```
import logging
def getLevelNames():
    for k, v in sorted(logging._levelNames.iteritems()):
        if isinstance(v, basestring):
            yield v, k

import pprint
pprint.pprint(list(getLevelNames()))
```

Example output:

```
[('NOTSET', 0),
 ('DEBUG', 10),
 ('INFO', 20),
 ('WARNING', 30),
 ('ERROR', 40),
 ('CRITICAL', 50)]
```

Comment: yes, that's how i came up with `_levelNames` in the first place (by looking at the source of the logging module). the question is more, whether there's a way without resorting to a private member.

Answer (score -1):

What about something like this.  Note Python 3.4 produces a slightly different dictionary than Python 2, but you can modify the function or the resultant dictionary to work around that if required.

```py
import logging
import copy

def get_logging_level_names():

    #! find logging's internal dictionary for level names.
    #! the internal dict name changed in python 3.4.
    try:
        level_names = logging._levelToName
    except AttributeError:
        level_names = logging._levelNames

    #! return a copy to prevent modification logging's local dict.
    return copy.copy(level_names)

level_names = get_logging_level_names()
print('level_names = {!r}'.format(level_names))
```

Comment: Modifying `logging`'s dictionary is a supported use case anyway, although you're supposed to use `logging.addLevelName` to do it.

Comment: My example doesn't modify the list.  Just retrieves the list (e.g. so you can display it in UI and user can select the level).  The copy was a safe guard so the user doesn't accidentally modify it.  Of course the user can modify logging level dict explicitly through the normal API as you suggest :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this might be better than my previous answer.  It returns a sorted list of level names.  You can modify to return a sorted list (by value) of dict pairs {val:name} or {name:val} if you prefer.

```
import logging

def get_logging_level_names():

    #! find logging's internal dictionary for level names.
    #! the internal dict name changed in python 3.4.
    try:
        level_to_name = logging._levelToName
        level_vals = level_to_name.keys()
    except AttributeError:
        level_to_name = logging._levelNames
        level_vals = [ key for key in level_to_name.keys() if isinstance(key,int) ]

    level_vals = sorted(level_vals)
    level_names = [ level_to_name[val] for val in level_vals ]
    return level_names

level_names = get_logging_level_names()
print('level_names = {!r}'.format(level_names))
```

Answer (score -1):

I too am dismayed that the module doesn't offer a public attr or method for this. Here's a terse solution that works in Python 2 and 3:

```
import logging
LOG_LEVEL_NAMES = [logging.getLevelName(v) for v in
                   sorted(getattr(logging, '_levelToName', None)
                          or logging._levelNames)
                   if getattr(v, "real", 0)]
```

Breakdown: The module name (`logging`) did not change, so we can avoid a `try/except` around an `ImportError` for py2/3 compatibility by using `getattr(logging, '_levelToName', None)` to get the Python 3 value, if possible.

In Python 2 we get `logging._levelNames`, which is slightly different -- it has both int->string and string->int mappings, so I use `getattr(v, "real", 0)` to ensure that the filter treats all the string values as 0. We also throw out `logging.NOTSET` this way.

Then we sort the values and map `logging.getLevelName` to get back to an ordered list of names.