# How can I get an array of all possible log levels?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I wish to get all possible, current, log levels in the application. I am using the standard logging library for python 2.7.

Something along the lines of:

```
logging.getLevels()
[DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL]
```

My use case for this, would be to pass it into argsparse. We define some custom log levels in our application, and it would be nice for those to automatically propagate into argparse.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('our app')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--loglevel', type=str, help='Log level', 
choices=logging.getLevels(), default='WARNING')
```

I can't find a function like this in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). The closest I can find is getLevelName(int level) which will return the string based off an integer.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846024/get-list-of-named-loglevels, though it does involve accessing an underscore-variable, so might not be ideal.

Comment: @ymbirtt Ah, that's a good link. I did search but didn't spot that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from the question @ymbirtt linked, I worked out this: 
It calls the _levelNames and then traverses it making only to get the string answers.

```
[v for (k,v) in logging._levelNames.iteritems() if type(k) is int]
```

In python 3:

```
[v for (k,v) in logging._levelNames.items() if type(k) is int]
```

In the finished solution:

```
parser.add_argument('-l', '--loglevel', type=str, help='Log level', 
choices=[v for (k,v) in logging._levelNames.iteritems() if type(k) is int], 
default='WARNING')
```

Edit: Swapped value and key around keeps ordering

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anylonger in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a shorter solution can be :

```py
list(logging._levelToName.values())
# ['CRITICAL', 'ERROR', 'WARNING', 'INFO', 'DEBUG', 'NOTSET']
```